# Lubuntu fglrx drivers not loading

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, lubuntu, gpu-driver

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 on my PC and it doesn't seem to load the fglrx drivers, it only loads the open source drivers. I have no idea what is happening with the drivers, purge and reinstall doesn't seem to do anything (Both drivers need different settings to correctly fit on my monitor)

My graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 5750

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more Googling, I found a working solution from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1080612

Copy and paste these commands into the terminal in order

sudo update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf

sudo ldconfig -n

sudo update-initramfs -u

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

Then reboot and the fglrx drivers should load